# Is D/A an integral domain?

Tags: ring-theory, integral-domain

Let D be an integral domain and let A be a proper ideal of D. Is D/A an integral domain? If yes, prove it; otherwise, give a counterexample.

What I did is:

Let (x+A),(y+A) be in D/A where x,y are in D.

WTS: either x+A=A or y+A=A

By def'n of quotient rings,
(x+A)(y+A) = xy+A = 0+A = A

Since D is an integral domain, ab=0 implies a=0 or b=0.

Thus, (x+A)(y+A)=A implies x+A=A or y+A=A.

So, D/A has no zero divisors.
Therefore, D/A is an integral domain?

Is this proof already correct or lacking to be complete?

Comment: "If yes, prove it" -- that sounds like something you, not we, are supposed to be doing.

Comment: The question will be put on hold for lacking context. What this means is that we would like you to share with us your own thoughts, may be a summary of things you tried. Otherwise it is difficult to help you see the light. Also doing that will dispel the suspicions that you simply want somebody to do your homework. Here's a suggestion. Check what happens, when $D$ is the ring of integers $\Bbb{Z}$. Please add your observations to the question body (click the edit button). That will put your question into reopening queue.

Comment: Your added thoughts are welcome, but painful to try to read.  Please see [how to use MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$ to format mathematical formulas.  You cannot prove $D/A$ is an integral domain without some additional assumption on $A$ besides being a proper ideal.  You can (as Jyrki has suggested) consider $D = \mathbb{Z}$ as a source of examples.

Comment: Your proof is incorrect. How do you conclude that either $x+A=A$ or $y+A=A$ from $ab=0\implies a=0\vee b=0$?

Answer (score 1):

> By def'n of quotient rings, (x+A)(y+A) = xy+A = 0+A = A
>
> Since D is an integral domain, ab=0 implies a=0 or b=0.

This step doesn't work.  You know that $xy+A=0+A$, but that doesn't imply $xy=0$; it just implies that $xy\in A$.

In fact, the result is not true.  To find a counterexample, I suggest looking at various choices of ideals $A$ in the ring $D=\mathbb{Z}$.